# How to set 2 different spark versions in .bashrc 2.4.0 and 2.4.4 in local

Tags: linux, bash, shell, apache-spark, unix

Need spark 2.4.0 for hbase and spark 2.4.4 for Kafka streaming due to jar dependency of hbase not available for 2.4.4 version.

So i thought we can use if else in .bashrc and use a variable to specially select 2.4.4 and set 2.4.0 as default.

```
export SPARK_HOME_240_VERSION=/home/user/Softwares/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/
export SPARK_HOME_244_VERSION=/home/user/Softwares/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop-2.7-scala-2.12/
export SPARK_CURRENT_VERSION=240

if [ $SPARK_CURRENT_VERSION -eq 244 ]
then
   export SPARK_HOME=$SPARK_HOME_244_VERSION
else 
   export SPARK_HOME=$SPARK_HOME_240_VERSION
fi
```

in bash

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ echo $SPARK_HOME
/home/user/Softwares/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ echo $SPARK_CURRENT_VERSION
240
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ export SPARK_CURENT_VERSION=244
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ echo $SPARK_CURRENT_VERSION
240
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ echo $SPARK_HOME
/home/user/Softwares/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/
user@user-VirtualBox:~$
```

Both spark must be configured and one variable must be set to 240 to get default 2.4.0 Spark. That variable value must be changed to 244 to open 2.4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup aliases to do this, I find it faster than doing exports:

```
alias 240='export SPARK_HOME=/home/user/Softwares/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/'
alias 244='export SPARK_HOME=/home/user/Softwares/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop-2.7-scala-2.12/'
```

to switch, simply type `240` or `244`.

Another alias could be set to quickly see which version is "on":

```
alias sparkhome=`echo $SPARK_HOME`
```

---

Note that there is a typo in your sample, you do:

> ```
> export SPARK_CURENT_VERSION=244
> echo  $SPARK_CURRENT_VERSION
> ```

Do you see it?  You are missing an 'R' in the export line.  So the "code" in your bashrc is never run.

Comment: My bad, while copying i copied wrong. But still even with 2 R's im getting same issue

Comment: It Worked thank you, But another small help. How to call this aliases in shell script. When i give ---------------------------------244 \n (space)
PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin  Error : 244: not found

Comment: Aliases only exist in the shell.  You must put it "in clear" in a script.

Comment: "in clear"  is a command, i cant find it in google. Or does it mean clear the screen??

Comment: Sorry, you have to type it in completly in the script, you cannot use the alias.